# Media query. Is there any sense behind the division: @media all or @media screen?

Tags: css, media-queries

Simplicity is a key to brilliance.

I see some sense behind `@media print` and `@media screen` tags.
But comparison `@media screen` to (`@media all` and not print) confuses me.

Is there any sence behind the division: `@media all` and `@media screen` ?
Intuitively by default I would prefer `@media screen` but what might fail in this
case ? Any good example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will miss all the other media types (that are very seldom used, but that exist):

From w3c page:

```
braille
    Intended for braille tactile feedback devices.
embossed
    Intended for paged braille printers.
handheld
    Intended for handheld devices (typically small screen, limited bandwidth).
projection
    Intended for projected presentations, for example projectors. 
speech
    Intended for speech synthesizers. 
tty
    Intended for media using a fixed-pitch character grid (such as teletypes, terminals,   )     
tv
    Intended for television-type devices (low resolution, color, limited-scrollability screens, sound available).
```

Comment: Thanks, but how browser detects media type of a gadget? 
Lets compare tv and screen. :) That is very interesting.

Comment: Well, I don't know exactly how this works. I guess that the tv browser is a special build that the tv manufacturer embeds in the tv, but surely somebody knows better. Anyway, you should know that there is a slight posibility of somebody viewing your page with @media tv set.